# Java timezone & AWS EC2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, timezone

I am receiving a ISO8601 time from the client, converting it into UTC,  and saving it as a timestamp on AWS EC2 server, with a DateTimeZone as follows

```
    DateTime groupExpectedDate = sentGroup_expected_date_time.withZone(cityTimezone);

    Timestamp groupExpectedDateTimestamp = new Timestamp(groupExpectedDate.getMillis());
```

when i run the code on my local server, the times are assigned correctly for that specific city. However, when I push to the AWS EC2 server, the times are wrong. Is there a configuration on AWS EC2 i should be performing?

Comment: I would add some logging to see at what point it starts differing from your local machine. I'm guessing it is using the system timezone at some point, and the timezone setting on the AWS server is different from your local server. There is nothing "EC2 specific" that would be doing this. The EC2 server is just a Linux server.

Comment: what type of object is `sentGroup_expected_date_time`?

Answer (score 0):

You should set `Timezone` consistently across your environment servers, either forcing the [Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) in Java code, or setting the timezone in your underlying OS (which is not stated in your question)

Which `Timestamp` class are you using? The one from `java.sql.Timestamp` or another?